# Laravel select2 set selected option on blade file

Tags: php, html, laravel, jquery-select2, laravel-blade

Laravel 8
I am creating a laravel 8 webapp. Therefore I am using select2 to create multiselect select fields. Using the select box for choosing the values and storing them in the database works like a charm. Now i want to create the edit field, where the selected values should be shown.

```
<option value="123" selected>123</option>
```

does not work in the blade file.
Could you recommend me a solution using the default laravel blade logic (@foreach, @if, ...)
If this not works, then i need more help.

Thank you

Comment: try with `<option value="123" selected="selected">123</option>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are a lot of ways to do this
let's start with the simplest one
I will suppose we have companies' array

```
$companies = ['google', 'facebook', 'amazon'];
$selectedCompany = 1;
```

1- you can just select the equivalent key

```
<option value="{{$key}}" {{ ($key === $selectedCompany) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$value}}</option>
```

2- you can use Components to build Option Component
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components

from CLI run

```
php artisan make:component Forms/Select/Option
```

laravel will create two files one for the view code and the second for the logic

```
resources/views/components/forms/select/option.blade.php
app/View/Components/Forms/Select/Option.php
```

create three properties $key, $value and $selectedKey

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components\Forms\Select;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Option extends Component
{
    public $value;

    public $key;

    public $selectedKey;
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($key, $value, $selectedKey)
    {
        $this->key = $key;
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->selectedKey = $selectedKey;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.forms.select.option');
    }
}
```

and the `option.blade.php` content

```
<option value="{{$key}}" {{ $key === $selectedKey ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$value}}</option>
```

now you can call this component wherever you want and pass it the properties

```
<x-forms.select.option :value="$value" :key="$key" :selectedKey="$selectedCompany"> </x-forms.select.option>
```

3- you can use `laravelcollective/html` package
https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.x/html#drop-down-lists

form the CLI run

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

now you can use the `Form::select` in any blade view file

```
{{ Form::select('company_id', $companies, $selectedCompany) }}
```

I hope it's helpful

Comment: the 'selected' tag works now. my error was that i forgot to change the select field to type multiple (<select id="##" name='##[]' multiple>
so that caused the error.
Thank you

Comment: where is the implementation of select2, and if suppose there have 50000 listed companies then will it work?